# What does the question mark mean in GSP/Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, operators, gsp

I saw this in my generated GSP pages. What does the **?** mean?

```
<g:textField name="name" value="${phoneInstance?.name}" />
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It's the "Safe Navigation Operator", which is a Groovy feature that concisely avoids null pointer exceptions. See http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_safe_navigation_operator

In this case, if `phoneInstance` is null, then it doesn't try to get the `name` property and cause a NPE - it just sets the value of the field tag to null.

Comment: Thank you! I had been googling it for a while but didn't find an answer.

Comment: For extra coolness you can also add a sensible default with the Elvis operator eg: `${phoneInstance?.number?:'+44'}` Rock groovy with the king baby!

Answer (score 4):

The `?` operator allows null values in Groovy (and thusly, GSP). For example, normally in gsp,

```
<g:field name="amount" value="${priceDetails.amount}" />
```

If `priceDetails` is null, this will throw a `NullPointerException`.

If we use the `?` operator instead ...

```
<g:field name="amount" value="${priceDetails?.amount}" />
```

now the value of `${priceDetails?.amount}` is null, instead of throwing a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

> This is very important feature in Groovy. If the object is null (ie,
>   "phoneInstance" is null) then it's provide "null" value. This feature
>   is called "Safe Navigation Operator". Simply when we use this feature , No need of checking the object("phoneInstance") is null or not.

Answer (score 1):

the safe navigation operator (?.) returns null if the object on the left is null, otherwise it returns the value of the right member of that object. so `phoneInstance?.name` is just shorthandn for `phoneInstance == null ? null : phoneInstance.name`

for example:

```
a = x?.y
```

is just shorthand for:

```
a = (x == null ? null : x.y)
```

which is shorthand for:

```
if(x == null){
    a = null
} else {
    a = x.y
}
```